# CollectionView Horizontally - the last Image out of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to achieve to upload images up to five from camera/gallery on a collection view which is only 1xN horizontally. However, when I have more than 3 images, the last images is not shown properly, it is partially seen.

In the following image, please pay attention to camera icon, which is partially out of screen. I am testing with iPhone 5s.

I have put this small project in the following repository: https://github.com/texas16/CameraCollectionView

[image]

Comment: I have check your project it is working properly, you need to scroll to the last element of collectionVIew, in your case scroll horizontally, it will show the last image also.

Comment: I am testing with iphone 5s. You may increase the number of images up to 10 if you are testing with iphone 6 or 6s. By the way, I did not apply the autolayout.

Comment: That was i am saying, have you try to scroll till the end of your collectionView, I have also with 10 images still no issue.

Comment: But you need to force scroll to the end. whenever you leave your finger from the scroll,  the last image slightly goes out of the screen as shown in the figure.

Comment: can it help [yourCollectionView setPagingEnabled:YES]; ?

Comment: Possibly your frame is out of screen.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara, I checked also frame, it is not out of the screen.

Comment: @MikeAlter, I have enabled paging but it is still same, there is no effect.

Comment: @casillas, your collectionview has a frame of (6, 45, 356, 131). Note that, the width is already out of bounds for a iPhone 5 device which has 320 width. You should add constraints to your collectionView.

Comment: I am using iPhone 5s which width is 375, not iPhone 5

Comment: iPhone 5/5s has a screen width of 320 points. Check https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your project, In this method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

Your problem is you have used "<"

```
 [aBlockSelf.arrayOfImages replaceObjectAtIndex:self.selectedPath.row withObject:chosenImage];
    if([aBlockSelf.arrayOfImages count] < NUMBER_OF_IMAGES)
    {
        [aBlockSelf.arrayOfImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"]];
    }
```

but that's why camera image not appearing at last cell so u have to used "<= "

```
[aBlockSelf.arrayOfImages replaceObjectAtIndex:self.selectedPath.row withObject:chosenImage];
    if([aBlockSelf.arrayOfImages count] <= NUMBER_OF_IMAGES) // use <=
    {
        [aBlockSelf.arrayOfImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"]];
    }
```

**and also you have not set your constrain or else if you don't want to use autoLayout you need to use Auto-resize**

[Check this example (Using Autolayout)](http://%20http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=20810539328006383433)

5s Screenshot

[image]

**Using Auto resize**

[image]

Comment: i am using iPhone 6 to run your code it works perfactly

Comment: I am testing with iphone 5s. Could you change  `#define NUMBER_OF_IMAGES 10` and test it again please?

Comment: @casillas i have uploaded example check it it works perfactly in 5s,6 all type of devices (check this edited ans)

Comment: your solution works, it seems that you have done autolayout, in other words, you have added constraints.

Comment: yes and if you dont want to use autolayout then you can use autoresize

Comment: How could I use autoresize?

Comment: Thanks Mayank. I have accepted and upvoted your answer.